# Equivalent sequelize [Op.any] statement for this sql?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a sql statement that looks like this:

`select * from my_table where 'energetic' = any(aliases)`

How can I build that same query from sequelize? I've tried a few things, such as:

`MyTable.findAll({ where: { {aliases: {[Op.any]: 'energetic'}}})`

...but no luck.  I get messages like `values.map is not a function`.  I've tried a few variations of the above but can't even see any generated SQL with sequelize, as it never even gets to that point before erroring out on parsing.

Answer (score 0):

For `"sequelize": "^5.21.3"`:

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import { Model, DataTypes, Op } from 'sequelize';

class MyTable extends Model {}
MyTable.init(
  {
    aliases: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  { sequelize },
);

(async function test() {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    // seed
    await MyTable.bulkCreate([{ aliases: 'energetic' }, { aliases: 'a' }, { aliases: 'b' }]);
    // test
    const values = await MyTable.findAll({
      where: {
        aliases: { [Op.any]: ['energetic'] },
      },
    });
    console.log(values);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

The execution result:

```sh
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "MyTable" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "MyTable" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "MyTable" ("id"   SERIAL , "aliases" VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'MyTable' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "MyTable" ("id","aliases") VALUES (DEFAULT,'energetic'),(DEFAULT,'a'),(DEFAULT,'b') RETURNING *;
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "aliases" FROM "MyTable" AS "MyTable" WHERE "MyTable"."aliases" = ANY (ARRAY['energetic']);
[ MyTable {
    dataValues: { id: 1, aliases: 'energetic' },
    _previousDataValues: { id: 1, aliases: 'energetic' },
    _changed: {},
    _modelOptions:
     { timestamps: false,
       validate: {},
       freezeTableName: true,
       underscored: false,
       paranoid: false,
       rejectOnEmpty: false,
       whereCollection: [Object],
       schema: null,
       schemaDelimiter: '',
       defaultScope: {},
       scopes: {},
       indexes: [],
       name: [Object],
       omitNull: false,
       sequelize: [Sequelize],
       hooks: {} },
    _options:
     { isNewRecord: false,
       _schema: null,
       _schemaDelimiter: '',
       raw: true,
       attributes: [Array] },
    isNewRecord: false } ]
```

Check the date records in the database:

```sh
node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "MyTable";
 id |  aliases
----+-----------
  1 | energetic
  2 | a
  3 | b
(3 rows)
```